# Sending an XML to WebSerivce in iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, wcf

I want  to send an XML Document(string) to WCF webservice in iOS.
I have done it in REST webservices.
NO idea how to do it in WCF service.
Can any one help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose WCF services as REST endpoints if you want.  How complex of a document are you sending?  Do you want to use SOAP or just POST via HTTP?